# How to iterate over multiindex rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have the following data:

```
                     Adj Close  year  
Date       month day                   
1989-01-03 1     3     1.164242  1989  
1989-01-04 1     4     1.211100  1989  
1989-01-05 1     5     1.218310  1989  
1989-01-06 1     6     1.229123  1989  
1989-01-09 1     9     1.239936  1989  
...                         ...   ...  
2007-01-25 1     25   10.753074  2007  
2007-01-26 1     26   10.644608  2007  
2007-01-29 1     29   10.714428  2007  
2007-01-30 1     30   10.665804  2007  
2007-01-31 1     31   10.688246  2007
```

There are three indexes but i want to iterate over 2 of the index values month and day. I want to find and store the data something like this:

> for month 1 find .mean() of all day 1 over Adj Close

this should be done for all the days in month 1 to 12.

How can i do this?

Comment: Clarifcation,  You wish to find the mean of all January 1st across all year?  Do you wish to do this for every day of the year?

Comment: `df[df.day==1].groupby('month')['adj_close'].mean()`
something like this?

Comment: @ScottBoston Yes Exactly! i want the mean of all day 1 across all year in the month 1. I want to repeat this again for day 2 in the month of jan across all years!

Comment: @Tserenjamts i tried the following `data[data.day==1].groupby('month')['adj_close'].mean()`  but got error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'day'`

Comment: is day not in your dataframe? or does it have another name?

Comment: Make sure your day columns is uppercase or not in dataframe `Name` or `name` are different

Comment: @Tserenjamts `day` is in dataframe `data`. `print(index.data)` output was `names=['Date', 'month', 'day'], length=4790)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

Here is 5 years of dummy data and adjustments to fit your input dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Adj Close':np.random.randint(20,100, 365*5+1)}, index=pd.date_range('2011-01-01', periods=365*5+1))
​
df = df.set_index([df.index.month, df.index.day], append=True).rename_axis(['Date','month','day'])\
  .assign(year=df.index.year)
​
```

Using `groupby` you can return 366 days a year (one year has leap date)

```
df.groupby(['month','day'])['Adj Close'].mean()
```

Output:

```
month  day
1      1      56.6
       2      53.8
       3      48.0
       4      53.6
       5      70.4
              ... 
12     27     67.2
       28     48.2
       29     74.6
       30     61.0
       31     66.2
Name: Adj Close, Length: 366, dtype: float64
```